# Update row using sqlplus from command line hangs (linux bash)

Tags: sql, linux, bash, sqlplus

Running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and sqlplus (Version 19.8.0.0.0) I am trying to update a row in one line from bash:

```
$ echo "UPDATE STORE.employees SET AGE = '25' WHERE NAME = 'Bob';" | sqlplus  $USER/$PASS@$HOST:1521/$SID

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Sep 14 15:31:31 2020
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Sep 14 2020 15:24:00 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

But I just end up in the console - like the command was never executed.

This works fine:

```
$ echo "select AGE from STORE.employees where NAME = Bob;" | sqlplus -s $USER/$PASS@$HOST:1521/$SID
    
    AGE
    --------------
           23
```

Any suggestions to why the `update` command is not executed?

Comment: There is probably an error occured and you can't see it because of "-s" parameter which is for silent mode. Try to remove it and give the script a go to see the error

Comment: If I remove -s it just shows that I end up in the SQL prompt.

Comment: Thanks for post update. It strange. The last try from my side would be to check the update statement. Is it okay to use NAME = Bob without single-quotes while launching using echo and sqlplus on linux?

Unfortunately I don't have linux based Oracle to play with

I mean shouldn't it be >> NAME='Bob' << ?

Comment: Surrounding with single-quotes gives the same result. See updated post.

Comment: Do you have permision to update ?

Comment: Yes works fine from SQL Developer gui. Just not from command line using sqlplus.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Here are some desperate check I'd make if no one answers:
1. try whether update is possible via sqlplus (login and then update)
2. try "insert" via echo + sqlplus
3. You are on client version 19 and db is on version 12. Maybe using client same version as the database will help you out.

Again. sorry I couldn't help. Good luck